# I want to prove by $\epsilon - \delta$ definition this limit. Is it correct?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

This is the limit:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}} = 1$$

I want to verify by the $ \epsilon - \delta $ definition that the limit of this function is 1.

My process:
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and we try to find a $\delta$ such that, if $ 0<\left | x - a \right | < \delta $ then $ \left |f(x)-L\right | < \epsilon$.
In this case:
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}} \qquad a = 0 \qquad L = 1 $$
Then:
$$\left |f(x)-L\right | < \epsilon \Rightarrow \left |\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}} - 1 \right | < \epsilon$$
I transformated the function by multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator in the numerator and in the denominator. Then, I eliminated the denominator, so the new function is bigger.
$$ \left |\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - 1 \right | <  \left |1- x - 1 \right |$$
Finally, I changed the negative sign, because the absolute value must be the same for positive x.
$$\left |-x\right | = \left | x \right | < \delta = \epsilon$$

Is it correct?

Comment: And what does all this mean? Is there some sort of connection between these several mathematical expressions?

Comment: I’m sorry I did not realize that I had not written the statement correctly.

Comment: Your proof should involve words, not just equations and inequalities.  For example: "Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since ...., therefore ...., and thus ....."

Comment: You don't suppose... Rather you have to prove this fact. Thus write "Let $\epsilon>0$ and we try to find a $\delta>0$ such that..."

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've just edited the question. Is my procedure correct?

Comment: Your last inequality where you eliminate the denominator is not valid. Rather you should try to use $$|f(x) - 1|=\frac{2|x|}{1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ and then work from here.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, your proof lacks two things:

First and most important, logic connections. How are the statements linked?

Second, you should explain what is the relation between the second and third lines.